# Databaseconnection

Tags: postgresql

what id differents between CloseConnection(con) and rollbackAndCloseConnection(con)?

Comment: What does the manual has to say about these functions?

Comment: What are you talking about? There are no such functions in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i suspect first only close connection, and second close connection and rollbacs transactions ;)